# Vue: Computed property not passing to child component (console logs "empty string")

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a dashboard to do some simple calculations based on user input. After having asked Google repeatedly, yet unsuccessfully, to help me with my problem, my hopes are that you can point me into the right direction.

Since my project's `app.js` file contains 300 lines of code, I will explain the issue and provide you with a Codepen fiddle instead of copy/pasting everything here.

Link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/bauhausweb/project/editor/ZqnkEO#

I'm both new to JS and Vue, I am playing with it using on-the-fly code editors (Codepen) rather than ES16, CLIs and those sophisticated things. Please keep this in mind when posting your answers as I find the syntax already quite challenging to understand.

**Actual Problem:** The computed properties `revenuesFirst`, `revenuesSecond` and `totalCost` from components #1 and #2 are not taken over to the 3rd component. When I console log them inside the 3rd component, the result is an `empty string` and when the app is rendering, the form fields ("Profits Y1" and "Profits Y2") display `0` instead of the correct amount. Inside their respective components, the computed properties work fine though.

For the sake of readability, I'm pasting here only the 3rd component which references the computed properties from component #1 and #2 as `props`. Please take a look at Codepen to see the whole app: https://codepen.io/bauhausweb/project/editor/ZqnkEO#

```
Vue.component('result-output', {
  props: ["revenuesFirst","revenuesSecond","totalCost"],
  data: function () {
    return {
      rF: this.revenuesFirst,
      rS: this.revenuesSecond,
      tC: this.totalCost
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculatedProfitsY1: function(e) {
      let cp1 = this.rF - this.tC;
      return cp1;
    },
    calculatedProfitsY2: function(e) {
      let cp2 = this.rS - this.tC;
      return cp2;
    }
  },
  template: `<form action="">

          <h2>Profits</h2>

          <b-input-group size="sm" prepend="Profits Y1" class="mb-2">
            <b-form-input readonly v-bind:value="calculatedProfitsY1"></b-form-input>
            <b-input-group-append is-text>€</b-input-group-append>
          </b-input-group>

          <b-input-group size="sm" prepend="Profits Y2" class="mb-2">
            <b-form-input readonly v-bind:value="calculatedProfitsY2"></b-form-input>
            <b-input-group-append is-text>€</b-input-group-append>
          </b-input-group>

        </form>`
})
```

Why is the above code not sufficient to "import"/re-use/make use of `revenuesFirst`, `revenuesSecond` and `totalCost` from the first and second component into the third component `<result-output></result-output>`? When you play with the app on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bauhausweb/project/editor/ZqnkEO#), everything works fine - *except* for the final calculation of "Profits".

**I thank you for taking the time to help and appreciate your input!**

Comment: There is no connection between your 3 components. You'll need a way to 'link' those values. There are multiple ways of doing it, either move `results-output` to be a child of the other components, or use a store, for instance vuex to share state between component.

Comment: As @RaduDiță said, you'll need to link your components - either set them as children of one another or use an [event bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) or [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) (a global data storage system which is slightly more complex).

Comment: I am not very familiar with this syntax, btw as others pointed out you probably have to somehow say to the main app that `resultOutput` is its component

Comment: Thanks a lot @RaduDiță , **Jake** and **niccord** - I will try my luck with Vuex which I never used so far. On a different note, it's a pity that such IMHO logical approach to hand over a computed property from component I to component II is apparently not enough for the components to effectively "communicate" with each other :( Once I manage to solve the above issue, I will post my answer here.

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it. Variable names are scoped to the component level. There is no upper level where variables are shared between components. So your var1 from component1 has no meaning in another component. This keeps things clean. Another issue is if you have the same var inside different components , how would you differentiate them?

Comment: Thanks @RaduDiță for the explanation. Since I thought that, to stay in your example, computed properties could be re-used between components, I've always given them unique names.

Comment: I've tried as much as I understand Vuex (from [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/mastering-vuex-zero-to-hero-e0ca1f421d45) ) to integrate it into my calculator app. The good news is that no console error is happening. The bad news is that it's not working. It would be amazing if you could take a look at the Codepen at https://codepen.io/bauhausweb/project/editor/ZqnkEO#